Can taut membranes and strings that are clamped at both ends propagate non-standing waves?
I'm going through an introductory course in acoustics and I'm struggling with the intuition behind standing waves.
When deriving solutions to the various wave equations we usually impose a boundary condition which the solution must satisfy, for example that a string is fixed at both ends. So far, I have seen many solutions in which there is a $k_n$ term, which is the wavenumber corresponding to the $n$-th normal mode. But does that mean that such systems will only propagate standing waves, no matter the initial conditions (velocity, displacement, position etc) imposed?

Mathematically, a wave is a solution of a wave equation with the appropriate boundary conditions. A wave equation alone does not define a wave.
Now, if we have hard boundary conditions - like clamped ends, mirrors, infinite potential well - this limits the possible solutions in comparison to what we could have in a free space, or for infinite sting, waveguide, etc.
A solution of a wave equation can be usually expanded in terms of eigenmodes, which for the class of the problems discussed in this threat are standing waves. The full solution however might not be a standing wave. E.g., it could be a pulse that is running back and fourth along the string - which is what typically happens when we pluck a string of a guitar.

(image source)

Is it actually possible to pluck a string and get that result?  Here's a video of a real string being plucked:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_X72on6CSL0

@Edward:  If you stretched the string so that it made a localized "pulse" shape, held the string at rest, and then released it, it would actually propagate two equal-sized "pulses" in opposite directions.  But each pulse would behave like the pulse shown above, being reflected & inverted when it hit the ends of the string.

@Edward perhaps you're asking too much of a guitar string. But here's a video using a spring designed for physics demonstration purposes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PsGZq5sLrw

Thanks for the answer! So the full solution in this case will be a superposition of standing waves, but will not necessarily be a standing wave itself?

@Philip that's correct.

https://mathlets.org/mathlets/wave-equation/
This is very useful for visualising how standing waves can sum to form a "pulse". To start, I recommend setting the animation speed to very slow, the number of harmonics to two, and displaying the Fourier sum. Even with two standing waves, the "travelling pulse" behaviour is clear, and you can see how you can build up to a sharp "snap" by adding more standing waves.
